# How to insert images in PDF using origami gem in Ruby(2.5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using origami `gem` in order to create PDF files. Its confusing as to how I can add an image in the `PDF` at a particular location(x, y) coordinates in the pages.

I'm using this method but it only reads the image:

```
Origami::Graphics::ImageXObject.from_image_file(path, format = nil)
```

How do I add this image object to the PDF pages?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Im using v2.5 .

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an image to Origami, you should use this method: `add_xobject(xobject, name = nil)`
where `xobject` is an image.

https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/blob/7d3f6fcdc32345a458e91d91a0172349f10aaac8/lib/origami/page.rb#L132

For example:

```
pdf = PDF.read('pdf-sample.pdf')
page = pdf.get_page(1)
img = Graphics::ImageXObject.from_image_file('sample.jpeg', 'jpg')
page.add_xobject(img, 'sample_image_name')
```

See another reference here: https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/issues/17